# Aplicação em Next.js dando erro Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {designId, id, username, download, path, links}

Tags: react, typescript, next.js

Estou com erro quando faço a chamada nesse hook numa aplicação em Next.js:^12.1.6:

```
export function useResultadoDesign(uuid:string) {
const [ listaImagens, setListaImagens ] = useState<ImagemGerada[]>([]);

useEffect(() => {
    if(uuid !== undefined) {
        ApiService.get('/imagens/' + uuid)
        .then((result) => {
            console.log("deu result");
            let listResponse:ListResponse = result.data;
            console.log("lista: == " + JSON.stringify(listResponse));
            let listaImagens:ImagemGerada[] = [];
            for(var i:number = 0; i < listResponse.data.length; i++) {
                var response:ResponseAPI = listResponse.data[i];
                console.log("Response == : " + JSON.stringify(response));
                console.log("Response.data == : " + JSON.stringify(response.data));
                const img:ImagemGerada = {
                    designId: response.data.designId,
                    id: response.data.id,
                    username: undefined,
                    download: undefined,
                    path: response.data.path,
                    links: []
                }
                console.log("ImagemGerada == " + JSON.stringify(img));
                listaImagens.push(img);
            }
            console.log("Setando listagem");
            setListaImagens(listaImagens);
        }).catch((error:AxiosError) => {

        });
    }
    
}, [uuid]);

return {
    listaImagens
}
}
```

Onde minhas interfaces são:

```
export interface ListResponse {
  data: ResponseAPI[];
}

export interface ResponseAPI {
  data: any;
}

export interface Link {
  rel: string
  href: string
}

export interface ImagemGerada {
  id: number
  designId: number
  username: any
  download: any
  path: string
  links: Link[]
}
```

Nessa chamada tenho o retorno do JSON:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "data": {
            "id": 1,
            "designId": 49,
            "username": null,
            "download": null,
            "path": "https://vecsy-941811080.imgix.net/backgrounds/49/shopping_bags_credits_cards_laptop_keyboard_concepts_about_online_shopping_that_offers_home_delivery_42299_1919.jpg?blend=https%3A%2F%2Fvecsy-941811080.imgix.net%2F~text%3Ffm%3Dpng%26ixlib%3Djava-2.3.2%26txt%3D5%2520Maneiras%2520de%2520fazer%2520compras%2520na%2520internet%26txt-font%3DGotham-Black%252Cbold%26txt-pad%3D30%26txt-size%3D36%26w%3D288%26s%3D6fa0bc9e1165ddb57d58e3ee9af6f03a&blend-align=left%2Cmiddle&blend-alpha=80&blend-mode=normal&blend-x=36&h=800&ixlib=java-2.3.2&mark=https%3A%2F%2Fvecsy-941811080.imgix.net%2FTeste_Vecsy%2Flogos%2FLogo_horizontal.png%3Fixlib%3Djava-2.3.2%26s%3Dd53f898a1977e80d1359f76182eeb10c&mark-align=top%2Ccenter&mark-y=24&usm=20&w=600&s=9682051cf48529becd0edb2435b3be2c",
            "links": [
                {
                    "rel": "self",
                    "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/imagens/1"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

E tenho minha pagina que chama esse hook assim:

```
const router = useRouter();
let uuid = router.query.uuid;
const {
    listaImagens
} = useResultadoDesign(uuid as string);
```

E quando rodo aparece o seguinte erro:

[image: Erro que aparece na chamada da página]

Qual melhor solução para resolver esse problema?

Answer (score -3):

Faça um console.log das imagens setadas no final para ter certeza que é um array de imagens. Me parece que o erro é que você está tentando renderizar algo diferente de um array.

Comment: Mas o listaImagens que faço um push já está sendo um array